# Boolean Logic - Realization with using only 4 NAND gates

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, circuits, nand

I am currently preparing the next semester of my program at university and I am stuck at a question of the "Digital Circuits" class.

Here is the task:

> [...] pump P1 runs when the fill-level of the tank falls below 90% (U=0), however only when the opacity sensor gives output (S1=1) at the same time. If the lower fill-level sensor signals with L=0 that the fill-level is below 50%, pump P1 runs (P1=1) independently of the opacity sensor signals (S1), as long as U=0 at the same time. [...]

The task is first to derive the Boolean equation for the combinational logic of the pump controller (output signal).

I ended up with `P1 = U'*(S1+L')`.

We are then to realize the controller using only NAND2 gates with the hint that if 4 NAND2 gates are not sufficient to realize the circuit, we should consider further simplifying the Boolean equation.

This is where my problem lies:

I can only get to realizing the circuit with 5 NAND2 gates:

`P1 = U'*(S1+L') = U'*(S1+L')'' = U'*(S1'*L)'`

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBBMWo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I don't see any way how I could possibly simplify it any further. Maybe somebody could give me a hint.

Thanks in advace :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unless I have made an error (very likely) I believe this can be done with 3 NAND gates. The truth table must look like this:
$$\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{rrr|cc}
U & S1 & L & P1 & \text{comments}\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 &\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & x & \text{can't happen}\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & x & \text{can't happen}\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}$$
Using a Karnaugh map to find the Boolean expression yields a realization that uses 3 2-input NAND-gates.

Comment: I am not sure the don't care cases are justified based on the question wording...Although they do make sense, as the tank can't be both filled more than 90% and less than 50%. This is probably the right approach.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Well, the case where the fill level is above 90% but below 50% is impossible (can't happen). My basic understanding was that they then could be treated as don't cares. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: Yeah, added this to comment too, looks like it is the only way to get less than 5 NANDs. Upvoted

Comment: Just a thought. Why would the problem statement writer take the time to say that if L=0 the pump runs independent of S1 ***only if U=0, too***? This extra wording has to mean something. Or else why did they bother saying it? It's too *definite* to be an accident.

Comment: I'd say the whole problem statement is quite awkward.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Perhaps. But that kind of wording doesn't fall out of the mouth by accident. I suspect the problem statement *intends* this. Perhaps the upper sensor has "behaviors" that must be accommodated by the logic for some unstated hypothetical safety reason. Who knows? Regardless, those words don't accidentally get written. (Or, I can't see a good way to argue they were an accident.) Perhaps it is intended that the student identify this conflict?

Comment: It seems like there are only three ways this problem can be solved: 1) If you're allowed to have a complemented output, 2) it's impossible to have U=1 and L=0 at the same time, or 3) there's an error or omission in the question. We don't have the full text of the question, so I suspect #3, but Carl has the most educational answer so I'm upvoting it.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborations, they helped me and confirmed that the way I understood the question, it is not really possible to get below 5 NAND2 gates. I am sorry that I omitted part of the problem text. It states that a running pump means P1=1. It also states U=1 and L=0 is possible, because the 50% sensor may be defect and in this case the pump shall not run (P1=0). (That's why i used paranthesis (U'*S1)+(U'*L') = U'*(S1+L'). I think the wording is unclear, but its a question from last year (cant ask the prof). more important is that, my basic understanding is correct. So thank you all! :)

Comment: @EugeneSh.  That kind of problem statement sounds quite good compared to the stuff that I get to work with, so perhaps it is intended as an introduction to "the real world"?

Comment: I'm pretty sure a double-check for U0 when L0 is low is carried over from a real-world requirement not to overflow the tank in case of a failed sensor. So "can't happen" of this answer ignores a safety requirement, which is... let's say, not ideal. Please do not follow the Boeing example.

Answer (score 2):

Eliminating unnecessary words we get…

> pump P1 runs … if U=0 only when S1=1…
> pump P1 runs =1 independently of S1 only if U=0
> pump P1 runs if L=U=0 and S1=x

```
  P1 = U’*S1 + L’ = ((U*U)’*S1)’*L)’    
  shows 3 (a*b)‘s meaning 3 NAND’s
```

Comment: This runs the pump for all cases of L0, not only those of L0 & U0.

Answer (score 1):

Why those parentheses? When L=0, output is independent of any other input, right?

So it is P1 = U'*S1+L' and it can be realized with 4 nands.

Comment: *When L=0, output is independent of any other input, right* - As long as U=0.... Not quite independent

Comment: Yes, but I mean it is dictated by external factors.

Comment: U is an input, not an external factor.

Comment: When it is under 50%, it is always under %90. So when L=0, U is always 0. External factor is that they being tied by physical reality.

Comment: This physical reality is reflected by "don't cares" in Carl's answer. I didn't check the equivalence of your final expression to his, maybe they are equivalent. But these steps should be elaborated.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting with a complemented output to reduce the number of inversions you need:

```
P1' = U + S1'*L
```

If you look at the Karnaugh map for P1, you can see that it's easier to simplify P1' than P1.

Comment: I don't think it helps to reduce the number of NANDs

Comment: @EugeneSh. Changing things so that the pump is ON when the output is 0 does improve things over saying that the pump is ON when the output is 1. So complementing the output does impact the result.

Comment: @jonk Of course, you can redefine the signals to their complements (not only output but the inputs too). But it is not what the problem is asking to do.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Does the problem statement say *anything* about the output logic value with respect to pump operation? If so, I may have missed it. Otherwise, I'm not sure I understand the *"But it is not what the problem is asking to do."* Could you elaborate?

Comment: @jonk Actually, you are right. The cited text does not mention the polarity of `P1`

Comment: @EugeneSh. And there's the point. Read carefully!

Comment: Yep, that could be a way. But this answer should operate in these terms and remove this negation and add the wording "assuming the pump is running when P1=0..."

Comment: @jonk Ok, I just re-read it: *"pump P1 runs (P1=1)"* so no, I have to correct myself again, it is stated explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

There's an active discussion here about the problem statement and its *interpretation*. I'm taking the position that:

1. You reflected the problem statement to us, accurately.
2. The writer could not possibly have *accidentally* written the part about the pump ignoring S1 when L=0 *only if* U=0, as well.

A careful reading of the problem statement suggests that it may ***not*** be making an explicit statement about the logic level required for the pump to be ***ON***. It *does* appear to state that P1 is the pump. Then it also appears to say that P1=1 when the pump is ***ON***. So there is a conflation of two things -- the pump itself is called P1 and *also* a logic symbol P1 is suggested, too.

But if one either must figure that the content writer *accidentally* added that indication about U or else is *allowing* you to make the choice about a logic level distinct from the pump state, I'd go with the latter.

And no, I don't find a lot of shelter in that argument. But I do find at least a little. Also, you noted that the question went on to suggest *"simplifying the logic"* if you cannot get to four NANDs. I'll take that as an added clue or suggestion, as well.

Therefore, you have your answer. Don't assume that the pump is ***ON*** when the output is 1. Instead, plan that the output is 0 when the pump is ***ON***.

Comment: It appears that it does state the logic level for the pump: "*pump P1 runs (P1=1)*"

Comment: @EugeneSh. You may be right. Let me see if I can develop a counter-argument! Hmm. Okay. Is P1 necessarily the output I must develop just because they say that P1 is 1 when the pump is ON? Maybe P1 is just an abstract variable, not necessarily the logic I must use. I might instead choose to create /P1 (P1'). But yeah. I'm feeling less certain, again. I'll edit to reflect it.

Comment: I guess if you develop a controller box with predefined interfaces...

Comment: @EugeneSh. I added some comments. One thing about P1 is that it is conflated. They use P1 to label the pump itself. They then use P1 as a logic symbol. A pump is not a logic symbol. These are distinctly different. You cannot set P1=1 if P1 is a pump. ;) I find some (not much) shelter in that.